# Dynamic form array with dynamic options

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I want to make a student able to choose several workshops in a dynamic number of school subjects

1.- I have a config array, this array have the number of options of the student will choose for every subject

```
let configarray = {initdate: 2019-07-01, subjectnumber: 4};
```

In this example for every subject the student will be able to choose 4 options.

```
let b = this.FormGuardar.get("opciontaller") as FormArray; 
for (let i = 0; i < configarray.subjectnumber; i++) {
     let preregistro = this._fb.group({
         preregistroid: [],
         alumnoporcicloid:[],
         tallercurricularid: []
         });
         b.push(preregistro);
         this.arrayopcion.push({ taller: this.tallerselect }); //tallerselect will display
the options of every subject every subject will have a diferent options
```

Also when i select a options this is my code for erase the selected option in the other selects in the configurations.

```
    selectedTaller(id, index) {
    let seleccionados = [];
    let array = this.FormGuardar.get("opciontaller").value;
    for (let a of array) {
        if (a.tallercurricularid) {
            seleccionados.push(a.tallercurricularid);
        }
    }

    let disponibles = this.SelectTaller.filter(function (item) {
        return seleccionados.indexOf(item.tallercurricularid) == -1;
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < this.arrayopcion.length; i++) {
        let data = [...disponibles],
            control = ((this.FormGuardar.controls.opciontaller as FormArray).controls[i] as FormGroup).controls.tallercurricularid as FormControl,
            seleccionado = this.SelectTaller.find(x => x.tallercurricularid == control.value);
        (((this.FormGuardar.controls.opciontaller as FormArray).controls[i] as FormGroup).controls.clasificadorparaescolarid as FormControl).setValue(seleccionado ? seleccionado.clasificadorparaescolaresid.clasificadorparaescolaresid : null);
        seleccionado ? data.push(seleccionado) : null;
        this.arrayopcion[i].taller = data;
        seleccionado ? control.setValue(seleccionado.tallercurricularid) : null;
    }
}
```

The question here is how can i make this code work for a dynamic number of subjects with a dynamic options for every workshops?

Comment: Ahhh! Those names are hurting my eyes. Would it be possible for you to create a working sample stackblitz replicating your issue? Plus, please consider using lowerCamelCase to name your class properties and methods. It's really hard to follow what your code is doing at this point.

Answer (score 0):

To erase the options, see [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56887985/how-to-remove-the-previously-selected-option-from-a-drop-down-menu-in-a-table/56891636#56891636)

If you choose create on-fly the list, you can make something like [see stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbjkvn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

You has a recursive function that take as argument an index, an array of controls and an array with the options to choose -in this case I choose between a list of languages-

```
getLang(i, array, languageList) {
    return i == 0 ? languageList :
      this.getLang(i - 1, array, languageList.filter(x => x.name != array[i - 1].value))
  }
```

If you has a function like

```
createStudent() {
  const auxiliar = new Array(this.configarray.subjectNumber).fill('')
    return new FormGroup(
      {
        name: new FormControl(),
        options: new FormArray(auxiliar.map(x => new FormControl()))
      }
    )
  }
```

You can has in ngOnInit some like

```
 this.formArray=new FormArray([]);
 this.formArray.push(this.createStudent())
 this.formArray.push(this.createStudent())
```

And our form is like

```
<form *ngIf="formArray" [formGroup]="formArray">
    <div *ngFor="let form of formArray.controls">
        <div [formGroup]="form">
            <input formControlName="name">
            <div formArrayName="options">
              <div *ngFor="let a of form.get('options').controls;let i=index" >
                 <select  [formControlName]="i">
                    <option value="null" disabled>Select Language</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let lang of 
                       getLang(i,form.get('options').controls,languageList)"
                       [value]="lang.name" >{{lang.name}}</option>
                </select>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Updated** We need check not possible choose the same language, so we subscribe to changes of the arrays options. So, if we choose e.g. German,Doraki,Spanish and French, and after replace German by Spanish, the 3th options becomes null

```
this.formArray.controls.forEach(form => {
      form.get('options').valueChanges.subscribe(res => {
        res.forEach((x, index) => {
          if (index > 0 && res.slice(0, index).find(a=>a==x))
            (form.get('options') as FormArray).at(index).setValue(null, { emit: false })
        })
      })
    })
```