# Angular Observable matrix solution

Tags: angular, observable

This complete matrix is Observable :

```
DDA     DDB    DDC     DDD     DDE    DDF
A   |    B   |  C   |   D   |   E   |   F
----|--------|------|-------|-------|-------
2   |   4    |  6   |   2   |   5   |   7
3   |   3    |  6   |   0   |   6   |   8
3   |   6    |  5   |   1   |   6   |   8
5   |   0    |  1   |   1   |   1   |   5
1   |   2    |  2   |   0   |   1   |   5

Here every column is an Observable
```

example 

**ObservableA[]  : over Column A 

ObservableB[] : over Column B ,and so on**

```
And next
ObservableB[i] = ObservableA[i].pipe();
And similarly further ...

where DDA , DDB , DDC,DDD,DDE,DDF are also Observable over respective columns
ALL DROPDOWNS ARE MUTLI-SELECT

DDA -> ObservableA
DDB -> ObservableB
DDC -> ObservableC
DDD  -> ObservableD and so one
```

### PROBLEM:

i want all dropdown to have unique value from there respective columns

and  **also if DDA Observable we have selected 2,3 value from dropdown**

then all other dropdowns available value on expand should be

```
DDB : 4,3,6
DDC : 6,5
DDD : 2,0,1
DDE : 5,6
DDF : 7,8
```

This is applicable for all dropdowns 
means : if DDC changed then all columns should change respectively

How can i achieve this . kindly help me

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57049514/dynamic-form-array-with-dynamic-options/57051543#57051543, you has an aproach with not multiple select

Answer (score 0):

from my comment, if are multiple, we need change a few the functions getLang

```
  //remember that array.value if the value of multiple select, e.g. ["German","Frech"]

  getLang(i, array, languageList) {
    return i == 0 ? languageList :
      this.getLang(i - 1, array, languageList.
         filter(x => !array[i-1].value || array[i-1].value.indexOf(x.name)<0))
  }
```

And, when change the array to not equal to null else remove values, that, in ngOnInit

```
this.formArray.controls.forEach(form => {
      form.get('options').valueChanges.subscribe(res => {
        res.forEach((x, index) => {
          if (index>0)
          {
            const group=(form.get('options') as FormArray).at(index);
            if (group.value) //if it's not null
            {
             //calculate in optionsSelected all the options selected before 
            let options=res.slice(0,index)
            let optionsSelected=[]
            options.forEach(x=>{
              optionsSelected=[...optionsSelected,...x]
            })
            //we make a filter
            let newValue=group.value?group.value.filter(y=>optionsSelected.indexOf(y)<0):null
            //if the result of the filter is an empty array
            //we give a null value, elese the filtered result
            group.setValue((newValue && newValue.length>0?newValue:null), { emitEvent: false })
            }
          }
        })
      })
```

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s74hdz?file=src/app/app.component.ts)