# How can i stop user to select same option in mat-select twice

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, material-ui

lets suppose i have 3 mat-select items in an array with same options in all of them. (*option1 , option2 , option3*).

1. i select **option1** in first mat-select.
2. i select **option2** in second mat-select.
3. if i select **option1 or option2** again in the 3rd mat-select . i need to stop that and tell the user that he cannot select already selected option.

how can i do that in type script selectionchange function ?

Comment: A similar question may have been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57849385/remove-selected-option-from-dropdown-after-select

Comment: what have you tried? are your options an array of strings or an object? do you have a stackblitz example? Do you want to prompt the user that something is wrong, or should you remove the option from the list so you prevent them from doing something wrong?

Comment: if you want remove the options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57049514/dynamic-form-array-with-dynamic-options/57051543#57051543 if you want to show an error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63046298/want-to-add-a-custom-validation-with-angular-reactive-form-nested-form/63048387?noredirect=1#comment111495682_63048387