# How to synchronize dropdowns in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have 5 dropdowns on my page which are dynamic. I want all of them to get synchronize with each other. Suppose if I selected value 1 in dropdown1 so in other dropdowns i.e. 2,3,4 and 5 value 1 should hide. If I selected value 2 in next dropdown so value 1 and 2 should be hidden in other dropdowns except the dropdowns on which I have selected it and so on. I have to write this code in typeScript with Angular 8.

I tried below code but it is not working as expected.In this code if I selected value 1 from dropdown 1 it will work fine but if I selected value 2 from dropdown 2 then value 1 will appear as well in other dropdowns which should not happen in my case.

```
  public _values1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; //These are values for dropdown
  public _values2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; //These are values for dropdown
  public _values3 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; //These are values for dropdown 
  public _values4 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; //These are values for dropdown
  public _values5 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; //These are values for dropdown

  onChange1(e){ //This is function for 1st dropdown
    const val = e.target.value;
    if (val == 1){
    this._values2 = ["2", "3", "4", "5"];
    this._values3 = ["2", "3", "4", "5"];
    this._values4 = ["2", "3", "4", "5"];
    this._values5 = ["2", "3", "4", "5"];
    }
    if (val == 2){
      this._values2 = ["1", "3", "4", "5"];
      this._values3 = ["1", "3", "4", "5"];
      this._values4 = ["1", "3", "4", "5"];
      this._values5 = ["1", "3", "4", "5"];
    }
    if (val == 3){
      this._values2 = ["1", "2", "4", "5"];
      this._values3 = ["1", "2", "4", "5"];
      this._values4 = ["1", "2", "4", "5"];
      this._values5 = ["1", "2", "4", "5"];
    }
    if (val == 4){
      this._values2 = ["1", "2", "3", "5"];
      this._values3 = ["1", "2", "3", "5"];
      this._values4 = ["1", "2", "3", "5"];
      this._values5 = ["1", "2", "3", "5"];
    }
    if (val == 5){
      this._values2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
      this._values3 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
      this._values4 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
      this._values5 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
    }
  };
```

I am writing the condition to dropdown values like this but as you can see all values in dropdowns are getting every value change with every function run. This is the same function for dropdown 2 as well. Below is the HTML code:-

```
    <select class="form-control" id="select1" (change)="onChange1($event)">
      <option disabled selected>Select</option>
      <option *ngFor='let v of _values1'>{{ v }}</option>
    </select>

    <select class="form-control" id="select2" (change)="onChange2($event)">
      <option disabled selected>Select</option>
      <option *ngFor='let v of _values2'>{{ v }}</option>
    </select>
```

and so on...

Comment: You should hide array items depending on item index. Not item value.

Comment: Can you please give me a example on JSfiddle or somewhere else? Actually I am new to typeScript. @Ken Bekov

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56887985/how-to-remove-the-previously-selected-option-from-a-drop-down-menu-in-a-table/56891636#56891636

Comment: Yes, I got the thing working. Thank you so much man for the link to solution. You made my day. @Eliseo

Comment: But can you please do me a favour. Can you please explain the code that would be so kind enough if you do @Eliseo

Comment: Is a recursive function, briefly. if we are in the third drop, index becomes 2. So call to getLang(2, languageList)-->(as i>0) call to getLang(1,languageList)-->(as i>0) call to getLang(0) that return all the languageList. Well, the call getLang(1,languageList) now can return all languageList else the value of lang[1]. Again getLang(2,languageList) now can return the response before (languageList else the value of lang[1]) and return this else lang[0]. I hope this has some sense

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you can use the `ng-container` to solve your problem .

In your **.html** file , code should be ,

```
<select class="form-control" id="select1" (change)="onChange1($event)">
  <option disabled selected>Select</option>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let v of _values1">
    <option *ngIf="v != selectedValue2 && v != selectedValue3 && v != selectedValue4 && v != selectedValue5">{{ v }}</option>
  </ng-container>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="select2" (change)="onChange2($event)">
  <option disabled selected>Select</option>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let v of _values2">
    <option *ngIf="(v != selectedValue1 && v != selectedValue3 && v != selectedValue4 && v != selectedValue5)"> {{ v }}</option>
  </ng-container>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="select3" (change)="onChange3($event)">
  <option disabled selected>Select</option>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let v of _values3">
    <option *ngIf="(v != selectedValue1 && v != selectedValue2 && v != selectedValue4  && v != selectedValue5)">{{ v }}</option>
  </ng-container>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="select4" (change)="onChange4($event)">
  <option disabled selected>Select</option>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let v of _values4">
    <option *ngIf="(v != selectedValue1 && v != selectedValue2 && v != selectedValue3  && v != selectedValue5)">{{ v }}</option>
  </ng-container>  
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="select5" (change)="onChange5($event)">
  <option disabled selected>Select</option>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let v of _values5">
    <option *ngIf="(v != selectedValue1 && v != selectedValue2 && v != selectedValue3 && v != selectedValue4)">{{ v }}</option>
  </ng-container>
</select>
```

In your **.ts** file

```
 //declare this in the global .
  public _values1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; //These are values for dropdown
  public _values2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; //These are values for dropdown
  public _values3 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; //These are values for dropdown 
  public _values4 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; //These are values for dropdown
  public _values5 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; //These are values for dropdown

    //declare this in the global .
    selectedValue1  ;
    selectedValue2  ;
    selectedValue3  ;
    selectedValue4  ;
    selectedValue5  ;


    //make the function for each select option 
    onChange1(e){ //This is function for 1st dropdown
    const val = e.target.value;
    console.log(val);
    this.selectedValue1 = val;

  };
  onChange2(e){ //This is function for 2nd dropdown
    const val = e.target.value;
    console.log(val);
    this.selectedValue2 = val;

  };
  onChange3(e){ //This is function for 3rd dropdown
    const val = e.target.value;
    console.log(val);
    this.selectedValue3 = val;
  };
  onChange4(e){ //This is function for 4th dropdown
    const val = e.target.value;
    console.log(val);
    this.selectedValue4 = val;
  };
  onChange5(e){ //This is function for 5th dropdown
    const val = e.target.value;
    console.log(val);
    this.selectedValue5 = val;
  };
```

Comment: Someone has downvoted the perfectly working accepted answer . What to do for it ? @halfer

Comment: Just accept it, it happens. People are entitled to downvote for any reason they like (including post vandalism). You seem to be getting more upvotes than downvotes, so I would not worry about it.