# How to remove the previously selected option from a drop-down but show in edit mode?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a form in Angular 9, let's say it's for a language school. I want that the user can choose which language to study from a dropdown AND to add multiple languages by using "Add Language" button which adds another dropdown. The trick is that in the new dropdown, already selected languages shouldn't be available in the dropdown options. I followed the first answer to this question and all good:
[How to remove the previously selected option from a drop-down menu in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56887985/how-to-remove-the-previously-selected-option-from-a-drop-down-menu-in-a-table)

So, I have a array containing all available language names:

```
languageNames = [
    {'name': "English"}, {'name': "Russian"}, {'name':"Spanish"}, {'name':"Czech"}, {'name':"Croatian"},
    {'name':"Italian"}, {'name':"French"}, {'name':"German"}
  ];
```

I'm also watching what the user selected with:

```
@ViewChildren("selectLang") langSelects: QueryList<HTMLSelectElement>;
selectedLangs = new Set<string>();
```

Then I let the user choose a language from a dropdown:

```
<mat-select formControlName="name" (selectionChange)="selected()" #selectLang>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let language of languageNames">
        <mat-option *ngIf="selectLang.value === language.name || !isSelected(language.name)" [value]="language.name">
            {{language.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </ng-container>
</mat-select>
```

on selection change I clear my selectedLangs set, the grab all the values from my form and add them back:

```
selected() {
    this.selectedLangs.clear();
    for (let c of this.languageForm.controls) {
      const selectedVal = c.get('name').value;
      if (selectedVal && selectedVal !== "undefined") this.selectedLangs.add(selectedVal);
    }
  }
```

and this is how I check should I show my option or not:

```
isSelected(lang: string) {
    return this.selectedLangs.has(lang);
  }
```

It works perfectly.

But, let's say a user in the future want's to edit his or her submission. When I fetch my data I add the selected languages to `selectedLangs` string Set using a `forEach` loop on my incoming data and `selectedLangs.add(lang)`. The reason I want them in that string set is if a user adds a new dropdown for adding a new language, their previous selected languages shouldn't be available in the dropdown options. But here's the problem with this logic - in my edit form I only have empty dropdowns for each language selected when the user previously submitted the form because they are in the `selectedLangs` set.

[image: language dropdowns]

*These dropdowns should be populated with languages selected when submitting the form but they are empty*

How to show previously selected values when I edit my form so the user can see which languages he selected but with the functionality that works just great when creating a form?

Answer (score 0):

with JS you can set the selected value with .value
selectElement.value = "selected value"; The value needs to be the same as in the option value.

Comment: The problem is, I don't have an option to select in the first place because the `isSelect` check returns `true` and automatically this option isn't rendered.