# Remove selected option from second mat-select which was from first mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have 3 mat-select mat-form-field along with a input filed container for each mat-select.
Three of the mat-select is populated with data from same array.
My aim is to remove an item from other two mat-select which is selected in a mat-select.
How can i achieve this ?
There is only single api i am having to get array. There is no request going on selectionChange in mat-select.

**.html**

```html
<div class="input_left_container">
  <mat-label>{{ "Target Slab 01" | translate }}</mat-label>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-select
      (ngModelChange)="getSlabPrice1($event)"
      formControlName="target_slab_1"  
      (selectionChange)="removeTargetSlab($event.value)"
    >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let target of target_slab" [value]="target">{{ target.slabName }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
      
<div class="input_right_container">
  <mat-label>{{ "Incentive" | translate }}</mat-label>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <input
      matInput
      formControlName="incentive1"
      placeholder="{{ 'Pay/task' | translate }}"
      value="{{ this.price1 }}"
      maxlength="40"
    >
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
      
<div class="input_left_container">
  <mat-label>{{ "Target Slab 02" | translate }}</mat-label>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-select
      formControlName="target_slab_2" 
      (ngModelChange)="getSlabPrice2($event)" 
      (selectionChange)="removeTargetSlab($event.value)"
    >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let target of target_slab" [value]="target">{{ target.slabName }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="input_right_container">
  <mat-label>{{ "Incentive" | translate }}</mat-label>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <input
      matInput
      formControlName="incentive2"
      placeholder="{{ 'Pay/task' | translate }}"
      value="{{ this.price2 }}"
      maxlength="40"
    >
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="input_left_container">
  <mat-label>{{ "Target Slab 03" | translate }}</mat-label>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-select
      formControlName="target_slab_3"
      (ngModelChange)="getSlabPrice3($event)"
      (selectionChange)="removeTargetSlab($event.value)"
    >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let target of target_slab" [value]="target">{{ target.slabName }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="input_right_container">
  <mat-label>{{ "Incentive" | translate }}</mat-label>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <input
      matInput
      formControlName="incentive3"
      placeholder="{{ 'Pay/task' | translate }}"
      value="{{ this.price3 }}"
      maxlength="40"
    >
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

**.ts**

```js
// LIST TARGET SLAB
getTargetSlab() {
  this.riderservice.getTargetSlab().subscribe((res) => {
    this.target_slab = res["success"].data;
  });
}

// FUNCTION TO REMOVE SELECTED TARGET PLAN

removeTargetSlab(e) {
  this.target_slab = this.target_slab.filter((item) => item !== e);
}
    
// GET SLAB PRICE
getSlabPrice1(event) {
   
  this.target_slab_id1 =event.id;
  this.price1 = event.price;
}
    
// GET SLAB PRICE
getSlabPrice2(event) {
  this.target_slab_id2 = event.id;
  this.price2 = event.price;
}
    
// GET SLAB PRICE
getSlabPrice3(event) {
  this.target_slab_id3 = event.id;
  this.price3 = event.price;
}
```

**service.ts**

```js
// LIST TARGET SLAB
getTargetSlab() {
  return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}listTargetSlab/`);
}
```

Comment: have you tried using 3 different arrays of `target_slab` for your 3 dropdowns. your using the same array for the all the dropdowns. once you filter the  original array selected item disappeared from the all 3 dropdowns.

Comment: it's a bit old, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56887985/how-to-remove-the-previously-selected-option-from-a-drop-down-menu-in-a-table/56891636#56891636

Comment: your don't filter the original array.your filtering  only the arrays that assign to the to the dropdowns. for example- lets say you have `target_slab1,target_slab2,target_slab3`  arrays.if you select the first dropdown remove that selected value from `target_slab2,target_slab3`.

Comment: There was another one problem i found in this. When i selected one value its deleted from other but if changed same option again both values are deleted from other option.
Is there any solution for that ?

Comment: what is your FormGroup have been used here?

Comment: Can you update it with 4 drop down?

Comment: yes I can. so if you select an option from `Target Slab 01`, you dont want to show it in 02 and 03?

Comment: @HansakaSandaruwan : Can you update the same sample with 4 dropdown?

Comment: dropdown can be selected in a random order

Comment: @yash :yes...but  i have 4 drop down ..i want it with 4 drop down..random selection of dropdon

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you use `form` as FormGroup

```
private _ngUnsubscribe = new Subject();
private target_slab = [];
public form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    target_slab_1: new FormControl(),
    incentive1: new FormControl(),
    target_slab_2: new FormControl(),
    incentive2: new FormControl(),
    target_slab_3: new FormControl(),
    incentive3: new FormControl(),
  });

  [1, 2, 3].forEach(index => {
    this.form.controls[`target_slab_${index}`].valueChanges
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this._ngUnsubscribe)
      )
      .subscribe(value => {
        const item = this.target_slab.find(item => item.id === +value);
        this.form.controls[`incentive${index}`].setValue(item ? item.price : '');
      });
  });
}

get targetSlab1Options() {
  return this.target_slab.filter(item => item.id !== +this.form.controls.target_slab_2.value && item.id !== +this.form.controls.target_slab_3.value);
}

get targetSlab2Options() {
  return this.target_slab.filter(item => item.id !== +this.form.controls.target_slab_1.value && item.id !== +this.form.controls.target_slab_3.value);
}

get targetSlab3Options() {
  return this.target_slab.filter(item => item.id !== +this.form.controls.target_slab_1.value && item.id !== +this.form.controls.target_slab_2.value);
}

getTargetSlab() {
  this.riderservice.getTargetSlab().subscribe((res) => {
    this.target_slab = res["success"].data;
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="input_left_container">
  <mat-label>{{ "Target Slab 01" | translate }}</mat-label>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-select formControlName="target_slab_1">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let target of targetSlab1Options" [value]="target.id">{{ target.slabName }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="input_right_container">
  <mat-label>{{ "Incentive" | translate }}</mat-label>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <input matInput formControlName="incentive1" placeholder="{{ 'Pay/task' | translate }}" maxlength="40">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="input_left_container">
  <mat-label>{{ "Target Slab 02" | translate }}</mat-label>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-select formControlName="target_slab_2">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let target of targetSlab2Options" [value]="target.id">{{ target.slabName }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="input_right_container">
  <mat-label>{{ "Incentive" | translate }}</mat-label>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <input matInput formControlName="incentive2" placeholder="{{ 'Pay/task' | translate }}" maxlength="40">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="input_left_container">
  <mat-label>{{ "Target Slab 03" | translate }}</mat-label>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-select formControlName="target_slab_3">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let target of targetSlab3Options" [value]="target.id">{{ target.slabName }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="input_right_container">
  <mat-label>{{ "Incentive" | translate }}</mat-label>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <input matInput formControlName="incentive3" placeholder="{{ 'Pay/task' | translate }}" maxlength="40">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: can i follow this https://angular-ivy-ajcffa.stackblitz.io ?

Comment: another guy gave me this solution ? can you check it out ?

Comment: do you want me to update code there? you dont like his solution?

Comment: https://angular-ivy-7tf9az.stackblitz.io please check it here

Comment: can you provide the code for the solution u provided ? stackblitz solution

Comment: oh yes, here it is. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7tf9az

Comment: while editing my value for mat-option is target._id.. that creates issue ...it does not work in the sense of adding target slab

Comment: hmm i dont understand what you mean?

Comment: while edit ...my formControl fills with value from setValue.. but when i change or submit the same again ..there is no value for my mat-select...its does not pass any value in its ngModelChange

Comment: can you make it with stackblitz?