# Remove selected value from dropdown Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

There are 4 select option related to each other, so when I choose an option from 1st select that value should be removed from other 3 select options

```
// LIST TARGET SLAB
  getTargetSlab() {
    this.riderservice.getTargetSlab().subscribe(res => {
      this.target_slab = res['success'].data;
      this.target_slab1 = res["success"].data;
      this.target_slab2 = res["success"].data;
      this.target_slab3 = res["success"].data;
      this.target_slab4 = res["success"].data;
    });
  }

// FUNCTION TO REMOVE SELECTED TARGET PLAN

  removeSelectedTargetSlab(index, slab) {
    switch (index) {
      case 1: {
        this.target_slab2 = this.target_slab.filter(element => element != slab);
        this.target_slab3 = this.target_slab.filter(element => element != slab);
        this.target_slab4 = this.target_slab.filter(element => element != slab);
        break;
      }
      case 2: {
        this.target_slab1 = this.target_slab1.filter(element => element != slab);
        this.target_slab3 = this.target_slab3.filter(element => element != slab);
        this.target_slab4 = this.target_slab4.filter(element => element != slab);
        break;
      }
      case 3: {

        this.target_slab1 = this.target_slab1.filter(element => element != slab);
        this.target_slab2 = this.target_slab2.filter(element => element != slab);
        this.target_slab4 = this.target_slab4.filter(element => element != slab);
        break;
      }
      case 4: {
        this.target_slab1 = this.target_slab1.filter(element => element != slab);
        this.target_slab2 = this.target_slab2.filter(element => element != slab);
        this.target_slab3 = this.target_slab3.filter(element => element != slab);
        break;
      }
    }

  }
```

---

The above code is the component.ts file that I tried.

---

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how can I achieve this? this code is not working properly.

My expected output is . when I choose an option from 1st select that value should be removed from other 3 select options.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56887985/how-to-remove-the-previously-selected-option-from-a-drop-down-menu-in-a-table/56891636#56891636

Comment: it is not working .. @Eliseo

Comment: It is not working in mat-select . Iam using mat -select. pleas help me !!

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this..somebody please help me I am new in angular....