Synchronize data between several ng-select elements
I have N ng-select elements which receive the same [items] array.
Is there any way to synchonize this data so that when an item is selected, it gets hidden in every other selector?
When attempting to filter my items array, if I add an element, that element just disapears from every single selector (even the one where it was selected), so it does not seem like an option...
I also tried giving my array a "hasBeenSelected" property, but I have not been able to hide items matching that condition.
app-selector.component.ts
<ng-select [formControl]='control'
             [class.is-invalid]='control.touched && control.invalid'
             [placeholder]='placeholder'
             [hideSelected]='hideSelected'
             [clearable]='clearable'
             [items]='items'
             [bindLabel]='bindLabel'
             [bindValue]='bindValue'
             [readonly]='readonly'
             [clearSearchOnAdd]='clearSearchOnAdd'
             [multiple]='multiple'
             [closeOnSelect]='closeOnSelect'>
    <ng-template *ngIf='labelTemplate' ng-label-tmp let-item='item' let-clear="clear">
      <ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet='labelTemplate; context: { item: item, clear: clear }'></ng-template>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template *ngIf='optionTemplate' ng-option-tmp let-item='item' let-index='index'>
      <ng-template
        *ngTemplateOutlet='optionTemplate; context: { item: item, index: index }'></ng-template>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-select>

app-selector.ts contains several templates that can be modified
@ContentChild('labelTemplate') labelTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
@ContentChild('optionTemplate') optionTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

component where app-selector is used
 <form>
            <div *ngFor="let level of levels">
              <app-selector class="mb-4"
                [multiple]="true"
                [hideSelected]="true"
                [bindLabel]="'name'"
                [bindValue]="'id'"
                [items]='users'
                [formControlName]="'usersOnLevel'+level">
  
                <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item='item' let-clear='clear' #labelTemplate>
                  <span class='ng-value-label cursor-pointer'> {{ item.name }}</span>
                  <span class='ng-value-icon right' (click)='clear(item)' aria-hidden='true'>×</span>
                </ng-template>

              <!-- 
                <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" #optionTemplate>
                  <div *ngIf="!item.hasBeenSelected">
                    {{item.name}}
                  </div>
                </ng-template>
              -->
                
              </app-selector>
            </div>
</form>


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56887985/how-to-remove-the-previously-selected-option-from-a-drop-down-menu-in-a-table/56891636#56891636

You could wrap the option with an ng-container element.


<!--Using ng-container wrapped ng-option-->
<ng-select>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ng-option *ngIf="!item.hasBeenSelected" [value]="item.id">
      {{item.name}}
    </ng-option>
  </ng-container>
</ng-select>



You could also use styling to hide the selected options.


.hidden {
  display: none;
 }
<!--Using ng-option with display: none style-->
<ng-select>
  <ng-option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngClass]={'hidden': item.hasBeenSelected} [value]="item.id">
  {{item.name}}
  </ng-option>
</ng-select>




<ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" #optionTemplate>
<div *ngIf="!item.hasBeenSelected">
{{item.name}}



I already tried that approach, I need to handle options using templates and it's not behaving properly :c

@Pablo can you post the html code you are using for the select and the template?

I just added html code of both components!
